# Modular equation with very large powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, big-numbers

I studying for a discrete mathematics exam and am stuck on this question:

Find the value of the unique integer $x$ satisfying $0 \le x < 17 $ for which:
$$
4^{1024000000002} ≡ x \pmod{17}
$$

I have been reading up on how to solve similar problems but none that look similar to this. Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$ is a group?

Comment: No sorry I'm not too sure, would you mind elaborating? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It means that the remainder of the sum of two integers after divison by $17$ equals the sum of their remainders after divison by $17$. The same holds for the product of two integers, in fact making $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$ into a ring. This is true for division by any integer, not just $17$.

This allows us to write the following:
$$4^{1024000000002}=16^{512000000001}\equiv(-1)^{512000000001}\equiv-1\ (\operatorname{mod}17)$$

Comment: Ok, I did a bit of searching and think I have an idea about what you mean, but how do I use that information to proceed?

Comment: This is your answer; clearly $-1\equiv16(\operatorname{mod}17)$.
It might be insightful to read an [introduction](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction) to modular arithmetic, and more importantly, to do many more of these exercises (:

Comment: I will indeed, thank you very much, you have been extremely helpful. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that $4^2 = -1 \mod 17$, so

$$4^{1024000000002} = (-1)^{1024000000002/2} \mod 17$$

This is because

$$4^{1024000000002} = (4^2)^{1024000000002/2} = 16^{1024000000002/2} = (-1)^{1024000000002 / 2} \mod 17$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this area of maths and I'm not sure exactly how you arrived at your second line, could you explain how the "/2" comes about? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: $4^2=16$.  $16^{1/2}=4$ is probably a better way to put it.  Thus, when he changes the base to 16, you must divide the exponent by 2 to create equivalent statements.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm still a bit confused as to how I should proceed though, can anybody point me in the right direction, even in terms of what I should research on the web? I've spent the morning learning Chinese Remainder Theorem and that is pretty much the extent of what I know in regards to this topic, I really am not sure even how to describe what I am trying to do, apologies and thanks for your patience.

Comment: The CRT is not useful here. Perhaps the large number is throwing you off. Try this: $4^4 \equiv (4^2)^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 (\text{mod}\ 17)$ and now do $4^5$ yourself. If you can do that, I think you're ready for the original problem.

Comment: The way I would do that is to go $4^5 = 1024 $, therefore $ 4 ≡ x (mod 12), x = 4$ I'm assuming that that's not what you mean though...

Comment: @KevinH I suggest the following preliminary exercise: compute $4, 4^2, 4^3, 4^4,$ etc. mod 17, and write them down until you notice a pattern. Make a big table. Then see if you can have that pattern make sense with the comments above.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I see what you mean. I am getting 1, 4, 16, 13 repeatedly. Looking at @T. Bongers answer does that mean that $x$ is 16?

Comment: Hey, sorry to come back to this but what is stopping you using another number? For example if I choose to use $4^4$ instead of $4^2$ I get $x = 1$ rather than $x = -1$. What I am trying to do is to is essentially emulate [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction#Problem_.232) problem by solving it in terms of the things I know.